# Hide div on textbox change without AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox that users can enter comments into, and then click save. When they click save, some code executes in the background, but their comments stay in the textbox so that they can see them. I want to display some text above the box that says "Comments saved" when they click save, so that they know that their request went through, since nothing else changes on the page after clicking save. However, they can then change the text in the textbox, and it won't save unless they click "save" again. So, I want the "Comments saved" text to disappear if they change the text in the box. However, I cannot set `AutoPostBack="true"`, because it will mess up some other stuff that's happening on the page. Is there a way to make the "Comments Saved" text disappear when the textbox is changed, without reloading the page? Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div id="savedMsg" runat="server"><p class="msgAlert"> Comments Saved! </p></div>
<div>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="Save">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"/>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void SaveComments(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code here that is unrelated
    savedMsg.Visible = true;
}
```

Ideally, I would set `TextChange="SomeMethod"` and include this in my code behind:

```
protected void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    savedMsg.Visible = false;
}
```

but I can't enable AutoPostBack, so this event never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the message on the `onkeydown` event of the TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox" onkeydown="hideSaveMessage();" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

with the Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideSaveMessage() {
        var div = document.getElementById('<%= savedMsg.ClientID %>');
        div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>
```

You could also use `div.style.display = 'none'` to hide the message but that causes the TextBox to "jump" to a new position, which is somewhat disturbing.

I used `document.getElementById('<%= savedMsg.ClientID %>')` to account for any modification applied to the div ID by ASP.NET. The simpler syntax `document.getElementById('savedMsg')` may work in your case.

Comment: This is almost exactly perfect, so thank you! My only problem is, if the backspace key is pressed, the message does not go away. It seems that the function only triggers if a different key is pressed. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I modified my answer to respond to `onkeydown` instead of `onkeypress`.